# Why does it seem like I am losing IP addresses after subnetting with the subnet mask of 255.255.255.192/26?

Tags: ip, subnet

Note: I'm not referring to 2 IP addresses that gets lost when using subnetting.

I think my math is wrong somewhere. Here is what I'm doing.

- **Class B Private IP Range**: 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255

To Reduce the Broadcast domain, I apply the subnet mask of `255.255.254.0/23`

This gives me following subnet among others

1. `172.16.2.0` => `172.16.2.1` to `172.16x.3x.255` (512 hosts)

Now, this where my confusion is:  I want to divide this subnet further into smaller subnets so I use the subnet mask `255.255.255.192/26` by borrowing some bits from host part.

As per this IP address subnet calculator on [Calculator.net](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html?cclass=b&csubnet=26&cip=172.16.2.0&ctype=ipv4&printit=0&x=72&y=13), I will get 4 subnets

1. `172.16.2.0` => `172.16.2.1` to `172.16.2.62`
2. `172.16.2.64` => `172.16.2.65` to `172.16.2.126`
3. `172.16.2.128` => `172.16.2.129` to `172.16.2.190`
4. `172.16.2.192` => `172.16.2.193` to `172.16.2.254`

**Question**:  What happens to IP addresses in 172.16.3.x range?  Why is it not showing in subnets?

Comment: How were you able to give it `172.16.2.0/23` as the starting point? If I try that, it gives me the error "Please provide a valid IP address.", which is easy to understand given it asks for an _IP address_, not a network block. And since it doesn't seem to take a network block, how should it know you're considering all of `172.16.2.0/23`, and not e.g. just `172.16.2.0/24`, or `172.16.2.0/22` or `172.16.2.0/21` etc. for that matter?

Comment: Note also how it doesn't say "Here are the possible /26 blocks that fit inside the block you gave" (as you seemed to expect), but instead shows "All 4 of the Possible /26 Networks for 172.16.2.*". It should be clear from the `172.16.2.*` format that it's picked the byte border as the cutoff for that output. (Sure, you might consider that arbitrary or unhelpful, but it never said anything about the whole /23 block.)

Comment: *"A classful network is an obsolete network addressing architecture used in the Internet from 1981 until the introduction of Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) in 1993."* - *[Classful network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)*

Comment: What school or curricula still carry those concepts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why it is not showing in subnets?

Because calculator.net is very much stuck in the obsolete "classful network" way of thinking – and even gets *that* wrong, too. Don't use it.

Note how it has no option to specify that the original network is a /23, with the only options being "class A/B/C". That alone would already rule it out as a reliable tool. But on top of that, it says "All Possible /26 Networks for **172.16.2.***" above the table, meaning that even the three options do nothing and the website just *always* assumes a /24 or "class C" network as the starting point.

([Visual Subnet Calculator](https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html) is much closer to reality; it doesn't directly give you a list of "all possible /26's" but that's because there's no requirement for all subnets being of the same size. There may be other good tools that *do* just list all possible /26's given a parent prefix; I don't know of any online tools, but it can be done in literally 3 lines of Python.)

---

One note regarding "broadcast domain", though: A smaller subnet (longer prefix), by itself, isn't what reduces the broadcast domain – the smaller number of *actual connections* (hosts, bridges, switches) being part of that subnet is what influences that. So if you renumber a /16 with ten hosts and one switch to a /28 with the exact same ten hosts connected to the same one switch, your broadcast domain is still the same too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I’m checking the  recommended site.

Comment: It is certainly easier to just calculate it by hand. Really, it's just 3rd grade arithmetic.

Comment: It is also a waste of time to calculate it by hand once you have more than X of them. We have calculators and computers so that we could do _less_ tedious work, with fewer accidental mistakes.

Comment: Yes, but as the question shows it is easy to get wrong *with* a calculator as well. Someone picked a wrong/outdated/buggy calculator, other enters wrong input and so on. Calculator amplifies accidental mistakes into systematic errors and misunderstanding. On the other hand, after a few calculations you just starting to do that unconsciously, without much thinking. You'll be only entering the digits into the calculator when I already had an answer. This is the way Feynman challenged and outperformed people with calculators, and while that looked crazy, it isn't that much hard to do.

Comment: @user1686 There's nothing wrong with using a computer/calculator **if you have enough intuition to spot a wrong result**. Calculators get things wrong (like in this case), people make mistakes. I might not be able to calculate 17*23 in my head quickly, but I know something's wrong when the result is less than 100 or greater than 1000.

Comment: It doesn't always assume a /24 as the starting block (it can't assume "Class C", as 172.16.x.x isn't). If you ask it to create e.g. /23 from 172.16.2.0 it gives you "All 128 of the Possible /23 Networks for 172.16.*.*" The usefulness here is that it gives you the numbers, so you don't need to count bits or count multiples of 16 (or whatever), but immediately get to see that e.g. the /28 blocks start at .112, .128, .144 among others. The byte border is relevant in that going e.g. from `172.16.2.x` to `172.16.3.x` the numbers just repeat, so there's no need to show that.

Comment: That radio button for choosing the class is a bit odd, since if it mattered, it would detect it from the given address. It does seem to affect the choices it gives for subnet size: e.g. if you choose "Class C", it only shows /24, /25, /26 etc., but not larger ones (since those wouldn't fit in a Class C block). But that's easily ignored, or you can just choose "any". So, no, I don't think it counts anything wrong, TBH.

Answer (score 7):

Reminder: there is no "class B" anymore. CIDR appeared in 1993 — 30 years ago, you probably had never seen any classful networking in your career. Just stop using these terms, "class A", "class B", those are long time forgotten. The 172.16.0.0/12 range is now considered simply an RFC 1918 private range, without any "default subnetting" inferred from the first octet of the address (as it was in classful networking).

The rest of your question is fully CIDR-based. The term "bitmask length", the single number of bits in the mask that is specified after the slash, is a CIDR notation; there was no such thing in classful networking. The notation like "255.255.254.0/23" is strange and not universally recognized; you can *either* use /255.255.254.0 (bitmask form) *or* /23 (CIDR bitmask length form) to specify the subnetting in the IP address. In IPv4 those are fully synonyms, in IPv6 only the CIDR form is used.

/23 (/255.255.254.0) networks (of 512 addresses each) are:

- 172.16.0.0/23 => 172.16.0.0 ÷ 172.16.1.255
- 172.16.2.0/23 => 172.16.2.0 ÷ 172.16.3.255
- 172.16.4.0/23 => 172.16.4.0 ÷ 172.16.5.255
  and so on.

Then, when you subnetting the network 172.16.2.0/23 into /26 (/255.255.255.192) networks (of 64 addresses each), you get 512/64 = 8 such networks:

- 172.16.2.0/26 => 172.16.2.0 ÷ 172.16.2.63
- 172.16.2.64/26 => 172.16.2.64 ÷ 172.16.2.127
- 172.16.2.128/26 => 172.16.2.128 ÷ 172.16.2.191
- 172.16.2.192/26 => 172.16.2.192 ÷ 172.16.2.255
- 172.16.3.0/26 => 172.16.3.0 ÷ 172.16.3.63
- 172.16.3.64/26 => 172.16.3.64 ÷ 172.16.3.127
- 172.16.3.128/26 => 172.16.3.128 ÷ 172.16.3.191
- 172.16.3.192/26 => 172.16.3.192 ÷ 172.16.3.255

See, all addresses of a "parent" block are there.

Why your tool output different result is the really the question we can't answer. Either it made an invalid calculation in which case there is a bug, you need to contact developers, or you gave it wrong input, like you entered not 172.16.2.0/23, but /24, in which case you should really get only first four networks from the above list, because 172.16.2.0/24 has 256 addresses from 172.16.2.0 to .255.

Comment: You can't enter 172.16.2.0/23 into it, as it asks for an IP address, and that's not one. It can't know the user was considering 172.16.2.0/23 (and not e.g. 172.16.2.0/22 or 172.16.2.0/21, or whatever).

Comment: Thanks @Nikita.  I did these calculations 20 years ago.  Will brush up.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: What happens to IP addresses in 172.16.3.x range? Why is it not showing in subnets?

Nothing. The program just can't know you're thinking about 172.16.2.0/23.

Note how the form takes as input an *IP address*, not a network block. Giving it the address "172.16.2.0/23" and asking it for /26 blocks just drops an error. With just "172.16.2.0" as input as in your link, it can't know if you're thinking 172.16.2.0/23, or /25, or /24, or /22, or /21... (For some reason, it does seem to accept the input "172.16.2.0/23" when asking for e.g. a /22 block, oh well.)

But it does show some /26 blocks other than the one holding 172.16.2.0 itself. Based on how it says "All 4 of the Possible /26 Networks for 172.16.2.*", it looks like it gives all the numbers up to a byte boundary, so that you can easily see that after 172.16.2.0/26, the next is 172.16.2.64/26, then .128, then .192 without needing to do the manual calculation. It's not necessary to show those for e.g. 172.16.3.x as the numbers just repeat. It never says it's giving you all /26 within a /23.

Of course that output might not be necessary for all users, but for some it might help so they don't need to think if it was .112 or .120 that matches a /28, in case they do need it.

If you ask it for /23 blocks instead, it shows you the networks up to the next byte boundary, i.e. "All 128 of the Possible /23 Networks for 172.16.*.*".

Answer (score 0):

When subnetting with the subnet mask of 255.255.255.192/26, it's important to understand how subnetting works and how it affects the number of available IP addresses.

The subnet mask 255.255.255.192/26 represents a 26-bit network mask. In binary, it looks like this: 11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000.

With a /26 subnet mask, the first 26 bits are reserved for the network portion, leaving 6 bits for the host portion. The formula to calculate the number of hosts in a subnet is 2^(number of host bits) - 2.

In this case, you have 6 bits for the host portion, so the formula becomes 2^6 - 2, which equals 64 - 2 = 62. Therefore, you should have 62 usable IP addresses for hosts within the subnet.

It's important to note that the first and last IP addresses in a subnet are reserved. The first IP address represents the network address, and the last IP address represents the broadcast address. These addresses are not available for assigning to hosts, hence the subtraction of 2 from the total number of hosts.

If you believe you are losing IP addresses after subnetting, it could be due to a misconfiguration or misunderstanding of the subnetting process. Double-check your calculations and ensure that you are correctly accounting for the reserved network and broadcast addresses.

https://allfeescalculator.com/